# ReactNative - Start some task and finish it when app is closed

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to start some task, close the app and finish that task in ReactNative?
I have to upload photo selected by the user and I need to do it in background.

Regards

Comment: Maybe use `AppState`?

Comment: @Li357 I think it will not work. App thread is terminated when app is closed :(

Comment: @Li357 Android has services. :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking of iOS there. Whoops.

Comment: @Li357 Unfortunately my feature is not supported on iOS (because I cannot open an app when screenshot is taken).